# MIcrosoft Test Manager and Code Coverage

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012, code-coverage, microsoft-test-manager

I have been using MTM for a time and, so far, so good. I am trying to get Code Coverage over the tests I am executing. I have set my controller with 2 machines: 1 webclient and 1 webserver. For the webserver rule, i have configured code coverage. Of couse the webserver machine is the one that has my application running on IIS.

When I fire my automated tests (that btw were not created using visual studio, it was created using [Ranorex](http://www.ranorex.com/)) I can see that its generated an .coverage file.

But when I open this file, it is empty and I get this message from Visual Studio:

> Empty results generated: No binaries were instrumented. Make sure the tests ran, required binaries were loaded, had matching symbol files, and were not excluded through custom settings. For more information see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=253731

Of course I have read

- http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=253731
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh698492.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj159523.aspx

But I have found nothing wrong in my scenario.

Does anyone have any idea what could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. It turned out to be a problem with the permissions of the user I was using to run the test agent on the web server.

After changing the user to another one who has more permissions everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Go and check if you find one of the following files in your solution: `Local.testsettings` or `TraceAndTestImpact.testsettings` and double click them in VS. A new window will open, there you need to select `Data and Diagnostics`. There you'll see a point `Code Coverage`, double click it and then select all the assemblies that you want to be code coveraged.

If that does not work, check if your PDB files are present next to your DLL files.

Comment: I do not have those files, but are they really necessary? All pages from Microsoft don't say anything about it. If so, how can I get those files?

Comment: If it is from a project that you or your team have developed they could be found in the bin folder of your project/solution. If it is from a thirdparty then it will be hard to get them and I think it is not needed to code coverage the code of the 3rd party assemblies because the 3rd party should check that themselves.